# Trying to figure out how to pause and resume in Cocossharp (BouncyGame)

Tags: c#, cocossharp

So I'm playing around with the BouncyGame. I made it so that when you start the game you need to press the screen for it to start. I would like to implement this whenever you play a new round as well. I tried to reuse this att the bottom of my code but it made it extremely laggy.

```
// Register for touch events
        var touchListener = new CCEventListenerTouchAllAtOnce();
        touchListener.OnTouchesEnded = OnTouchesEnded;

        touchListener.OnTouchesMoved = OnTouchesEnded;
        AddEventListener(touchListener, this);


    }

    void OnTouchesEnded(List<CCTouch> touches, CCEvent touchEvent)
    {
        if (touches.Count > 0)
        { 
            Schedule(RunGameLogic);
            scoreLabel.Text = "Score: 0";
            paddleSprite.RunAction(new CCMoveTo(.1f, new CCPoint(touches[0].Location.X, paddleSprite.PositionY)));
        }
    }
```

I have no idea how to do this, tried for 2 hours with 0 results. Any suggestions are welcome.

Here's the full code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using CocosSharp;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;

namespace CocosSharpGameTest
{
public class IntroLayer : CCLayerColor
{

    // Define a label variable
    CCLabel scoreLabel;
    CCSprite paddleSprite, ballSprite;

    public IntroLayer() : base(CCColor4B.Black)
    {

        // create and initialize a Label
        scoreLabel = new CCLabel("Tap to GO!", "Arial", 80, CCLabelFormat.SystemFont);

        // add the label as a child to this Layer
        scoreLabel.PositionX = 50;
        scoreLabel.PositionY = 1000;
        scoreLabel.AnchorPoint = CCPoint.AnchorUpperLeft;
        AddChild(scoreLabel);

        paddleSprite = new CCSprite("paddle.png");
        AddChild(paddleSprite);

        ballSprite = new CCSprite("ball.png");
        AddChild(ballSprite);

    }

    protected override void AddedToScene()
    {
        base.AddedToScene();

        // Use the bounds to layout the positioning of our drawable assets
        CCRect bounds = VisibleBoundsWorldspace;

        // position the label on the center of the screen


        paddleSprite.PositionX = 100;
        paddleSprite.PositionY = 100;
        ballSprite.PositionX = 320;
        ballSprite.PositionY = 640;

        // Register for touch events
        var touchListener = new CCEventListenerTouchAllAtOnce();
        touchListener.OnTouchesEnded = OnTouchesEnded;

        touchListener.OnTouchesMoved = OnTouchesEnded;
        AddEventListener(touchListener, this);


    }

    void OnTouchesEnded(List<CCTouch> touches, CCEvent touchEvent)
    {
        if (touches.Count > 0)
        { 
            Schedule(RunGameLogic);
            scoreLabel.Text = "Score: 0";
            paddleSprite.RunAction(new CCMoveTo(.1f, new CCPoint(touches[0].Location.X, paddleSprite.PositionY)));
        }
    }
    float ballXVelocity;
    float ballYVelocity;
    // How much to modify the ball's y velocity per second:
    const float gravity = 140;

    int score = 0;

    void RunGameLogic(float frameTimeInSeconds)
    {
        // This is a linear approximation, so not 100% accurate
        ballYVelocity += frameTimeInSeconds * -gravity;
        ballSprite.PositionX += ballXVelocity * frameTimeInSeconds;
        ballSprite.PositionY += ballYVelocity * frameTimeInSeconds;

        bool overlap = ballSprite.BoundingBoxTransformedToParent.IntersectsRect(paddleSprite.BoundingBoxTransformedToParent);
        bool movingDown = ballYVelocity < 0;
        if (overlap && movingDown)
        {
            ballYVelocity *= -1;
            const float minXVelocity = -300;
            const float maxXVelocity = 300;
            ballXVelocity = CCRandom.GetRandomFloat(minXVelocity, maxXVelocity);

            score++;
            scoreLabel.Text = "Score: "  + score;
        }

        float ballRight = ballSprite.BoundingBoxTransformedToParent.MaxX;
        float ballLeft = ballSprite.BoundingBoxTransformedToParent.MinX;

        float screenRight = VisibleBoundsWorldspace.MaxX;
        float screenLeft = VisibleBoundsWorldspace.MinX;

        bool shouldReflectXVelocity =
            (ballRight > screenRight && ballXVelocity > 0) ||
            (ballLeft < screenLeft && ballXVelocity < 0);
        if (shouldReflectXVelocity)
        {
            ballXVelocity *= -1;
        }
        if (ballSprite.PositionY < VisibleBoundsWorldspace.MinY)
        {
            ballSprite.PositionX = 320;
            ballSprite.PositionY = 640;

            ballXVelocity = 0;
            ballYVelocity = 0;
            ballYVelocity *= -1;
            scoreLabel.Text = "Score: 0";
            score = 0;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out!
There is an "Unschedule" Method built into Cocossharp.
Ref. https://developer.xamarin.com/api/namespace/CocosSharp/

I just added

`Unschedule(RunGameLogic);`

at the very en of my RunGameLogic method under

`if (ballSprite.PositionY < VisibleBoundsWorldspace.MinY)`

So once the ballSprite is out of bounds it will Unschedule what i Scheduled in my OntouchesEnded method. That means the code goes back to listening for touches.

Might have made some errors, but this is as best I could figure it out and it works!